# Change destination file name in Copy Files in Pentaho Kettle

Tags: copy, move, pentaho, kettle

Good day,

In Kettle Pentaho, if use `Move files...`, then we can edit the file name in the destination, like specify date time format, so the file like `abc.txt` will become `abc02012015.txt` in the destination.

However, in `Copy files...`, I cant see this option. Anyway to do the same things as `Move files...`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try "Copy or Move result filenames" Step. Here you can append a date pattern while copying files.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I have some reason which is must use the `Copy files...` step, so if possible, i do not want to change the step, can I do the same thing in `Copy files...` ?

Comment: I fear there is no direct solution to this !!.But as a turnaround, you can use "variable" to define the changed filenames and use it as the "File/Folder Destination" in     copy files. !!

Answer (score 0):

You can check "Destination is file" in Settings in Copy file step and then in "Destination File/Folder" write folder with specify filename